# Enable webdriver logging for firefox in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I want to enable webdriver logging in firefox when using selenium.
I tried setting the desired capabilities as below but it doesn't work

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('-headless')
options.log.level = 'trace'

dc = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
dc['env'] = { "MOZ_LOG": "nsHttp:5", "MOZ_LOG_FILE": "/home/xyz/sample.log" }
self._session = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver', options=options, desired_capabilities=dc)
print(self._session.desired_capabilities)
```

This is the output I get

```
{'acceptInsecureCerts': True, 'browserName': 'firefox', 'browserVersion': '73.0.1', 'moz:accessibilityChecks': False, 'moz:buildID': '20200217142647', 'moz:geckodriverVersion': '0.26.0', 'moz:headless': True, 'moz:processID': 10017, 'moz:profile': '/tmp/rust_mozprofileSubcz0', 'moz:shutdownTimeout': 60000, 'moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin': False, 'moz:webdriverClick': True, 'pageLoadStrategy': 'normal', 'platformName': 'linux', 'platformVersion': '5.3.0-40-generic', 'rotatable': False, 'setWindowRect': True, 'strictFileInteractability': False, 'timeouts': {'implicit': 0, 'pageLoad': 300000, 'script': 30000}, 'unhandledPromptBehavior': 'dismiss and notify'}
```

I'm using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities/firefoxOptions#Env as a reference

Comment: Hi did you solve this?